# Append to a pipe and pass on?

Tags: shell, pipe, output, bc

I have a simple bash function dividing two numbers:

```
echo "750/12.5" | bc
```

I'd like to take the output from `bc` and append `/24` and pipe said result to another instance of `bc`.

Something like:

```
echo "750/12.5" | bc | echo $1 + "/24" | bc
```

Where `$1` is the piped result.

*P.S. I realize I could just do `echo "750/12.5/24" | bc` my question is more in regards to the appending of text to a pipe result.*

Comment: `echo $(echo "750/12.5" | bc )/24" | bc`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti nice I hadn't considered that approach.

Comment: @DopeGhoti This should be an answer. It should be the accepted answer, that's the simplest and most natural way to do it.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks; that means something coming from you (:

Comment: worth noticing `vipe` as an interactive on-the-pipe `vi` session.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the simplest of the options, this does append to the pipe stream:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | { bc; echo "/24"; }
60
/24
```

However that has an unexpected newline, to avoid that you need to either use tr:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | { bc | tr -d '\n' ; echo "/24"; }
60/24
```

Or, given the fact that a command expansion removes trailing newlines:

```
$ printf '%s' $( echo "750/12.5" | bc ); echo "/24"
60/24
```

But probably, the correct way should be similar to:

```
$ echo "$(echo "750/12.5" | bc )/24"
60/24
```

Which, to be used in bc, could be written as this:

```
$ bc <<<"$(bc <<<"750/12.5")/24"
2
```

Which, to get a reasonable floating number precision should be something like:

```
$ bc <<<"scale=10;$(bc <<<"scale=5;750/12.5")/24"
2.5000000000
```

Note the need of two scale, as there are two instances of bc.

Of course, one instance of bc needs only one scale:

```
$ bc <<<"scale=5;750/12.5/24"
```

In fact, what you should be thinking about is in terms of an string:

```
$ a=$(echo "750/12.5")        # capture first string.
$ echo "$a/24" | bc           # extend the string
2
```

The comment about scale from above is still valid here.

Comment: Simple??? Why not a simple command substitution?

Comment: @Gilles A `{…}` **is** simple. The answer walks toward showing the user a "command substitution" as the best solution. Read again.

Answer (score 38):

I achieved this using `sed` and replacing the end of the line:

```
echo "my text" | sed 's/$/ more text/'
```

Returns:

```
my text more text
```

Your example:

```
echo "750/12.5" | bc | sed 's/$/\/24/' | bc
```

Comment: This doesn't work for multiline text input. In my case, I wanted to append an extra line to multiline text and process it. Ended up using:

(figlet my_text && echo "new line") | boxes

Comment: Hugo, you're a command line ninja w/this! Awesome man, this is great!

Answer (score 21):

Alternative approach:

**TL;DR: Use `cat` to concatenate with stdin (`-`) as an argument. Note that it'll newline-separate your concatenated streams; remove if undesired.**

Unfortunately this approach is a bit cumbersome for your particular use case since `bc` fails if there's a newline in the middle of that expression:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | bc | cat - <(echo "/24") | bc
60
(standard_in) 2: parse error
```

You can work around that by deleting the newline from the original `bc` result:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | bc | tr -d '\n' | cat - <(echo "/24") | bc
2
```

However, I came upon this question by googling "bash append to pipe", and in my case I actually *do* want that newline between the concatenations. So for those here for the same reason, use `| cat - <(...)`:

```
$ echo foo | cat - <(echo bar)
foo
bar
$ echo foo | cat - <(echo bar) | sort | cat - <(echo last_line)
bar
foo
last_line
$ echo foo | cat - <(echo bar) | sort | cat <(echo header) - <(echo last_line)
header
bar
foo
last_line
```

Comment: This is the (elegant and) correct answer.

Comment: How do you append with a content of a file?

Comment: instead of the first : `echo "first part..."` (which adds a newline), use `printf "%s" "first part...."` (or `printf "first part..."` if there are no % in it) which will not put a newline, and thus makes appending the following of the line of computation easier)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this seems to work using xargs:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | bc |xargs -I{} echo "{}+20" |bc
80
```

Or even:

```
$ echo "750/12.5" | bc |echo "$(</dev/stdin)+20" |bc
80
```

And why not :

```
$ bc <<<20+$(bc <<<"750/12.5")
80
```

Comment: Why not? Because it's unnecessarily complicated. Use a command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk` to insert/append anything to the pipe:

```shellsession
$ date | awk 'BEGIN{print "prefix line"} {print}  END{print "suffix  line"}'
prefix line
Mo 21. Aug 15:24:30 CEST 2023
suffix  line
```

where

- `date` - is your input pipe (current date for example here)
- `BEGIN{print "prefix line"}` - this block will insert output before main
- `{print}` - prints input pipe's contents; one could do some processing here if needed
- `END{print "suffix  line"}`  - this appends output after main

To do same in single line, just use `printf`:

```shellsession
$ date | awk 'BEGIN{printf("prefix line >> ")} {printf($0)}  END{printf(" << suffix  line")}'
prefix line >> Mo 21. Aug 15:32:08 CEST 2023 << suffix  line/upload/sc505enb/tmp>

$ echo "750/12.5" | bc | awk '{printf($0)}  END{printf("/24\n")}'
60/24
```

Answer (score -1):

another possible BASH way - create a helper function which processes the stdin with `read` command and then prints extra line(s):

```
$ function append_lines(){ local data; while read -r data; do echo -en "$data"; done; echo "$*"; }

$ date | append_lines " +suffice_;line1" " ++line2" "  +++line_3"
[Mon Aug 21 16:00:37 CEST 2023][ +suffice_;line1  ++line2   +++line_3]

$ echo "750/12.5" | bc | append_lines "/24" | bc
2
```

where

- `while read -r data; do echo -en "$data"; done;` - just passes the stdin (pipe) through. remove the `-en` modifier to print separate input lines.
- `echo "$*";` - prints all arguments of append_lines() to stdout

Comment: would be nice to know why this solution was downgraded?